# php html div set POST variable in click

Tags: javascript, php, html

hello i want to set a $_POST value in php when someone click a div element , here's part of my code :

```
<?php 
 $looperone = 1;
 $judulcountquery = "SELECT nomorsoal FROM soal";
 $judulcountrun = mysqli_query($konek,$judulcountquery);

 if ( $judulcountrun == FALSE ) {
   die(mysqli_error());
 } else {
 }

 $judulcount = mysqli_num_rows($judulcountrun);
 $amountofrows = $judulcount;

 while($looperone == 1) {
    $judulherequery = "SELECT * FROM soal WHERE nomorsoal = $amountofrows";
    $judulsatuqueryconnect = mysqli_query($konek,$judulherequery);
    $judulsatufetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($judulsatuqueryconnect);

    if($judulsatufetch != NULL) {
       $judulsatu = $judulsatufetch['judul'];
    } else { 
       break;
    }

    $judulnya = $judulsatufetch['judul'];
    echo "<div class=\"head-main-recenttest-result\" style=\"text-   decoration:none;\">".    "<a href=\"bacasoal.php\">".$amountofrows.".".$judulnya."    </a></div>";
    $looperone++;
    $amountofrows--;
}
?>
```

example of output from echo :

```html
<div class="head-main-recenttest-result" style="text-decoration:none;">
     <a href="bacasoal.php">Latihan 1</a>
</div>
```

as you see that only will redirect people to the link without giving post data ,  anyone know the method ? also im new so i can't ask well

Comment: are you asking abou `AJAX` post method or `form submit` post?

Comment: Set a get value "bacasoal.php?data=". $data ... Post is just possible in a form or through ajax

Comment: i dont know ajax sadly '-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of your code, you are not sending any post `variable`  to the `bacasoal.php`. If you just want to submit then this will suffice.

```
<form method="post" action="bacasoal.php">
    <div class="head-main-recenttest-result" style="text-decoration:none;">
       <input type="submit" name="button" value="Latihan 1">
     </div>
</form>
```

Note: Your `<a>` tag was replaced by a an `submit` input

And if you want to do it via `AJAX` when click on the `<a>` then

**HTML**

```
<div class="head-main-recenttest-result" style="text-decoration:none;">
     <a href="#">Latihan 1</a>
</div>
```

**AJAX**

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "bacasoal.php",
        type: "post",
        success:(unction(){
            alert("success");
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    })
});
```

In the first approach the page will be redirected to `bacasoal.php`.
In second one the page will stay(unless you make it to).

Comment: thanks for sharing the ajax but i dont understand it .-.